# MassTransit Round-Robin balance keeps sending message to the same queue even though it's busy

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, castle-windsor, masstransit

I am trying to set up MassTransit with RabbitMQ for my application.

I am using CastleWindsor DI and .Net Framework 4.7.

The way I register my consumers and bus in the Program.cs is:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(configurationProvider.RabbitHostName);

        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedFirstHandler>();
        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedSecondHandler>();

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("addedFactQueue", ec =>
        {    
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
        });
    }));

});

IBusControl busControl = container.Kernel.Resolve<IBusControl>();
busControl.StartAsync();
```

An example of an Handler is:

```
internal class FactAddedFirstHandler : IConsumer<FactAddedEvent>
{

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<FactAddedEvent> context)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Let's call this main running application simply as **Application**.
What I want to achieve are 2 different things:

1) whenever a **FactAddedEvent** is thrown (from another service) then **Application** delivers the message to both consumers: FactAddedFirstHandler and FactAddedSecondHandler.

This happens correctly because if I understood correctly MassTransit creates an exchange and delivers the message to all the consumers subscribed to that message.

2) if I run 2 instances of **Application** (let's call them **Application1** and **Application2**) then Round-Robin is applied. Meaning that RabbitMQ balances the messages to the **Application** istance that is free.

This happens *partly* correctly. Meaning that if I have both istances up and running and try to send a **FactAddedEvent** then one time the event is received by **Application1** and one time by **Application2**.
Also, if I bring for example **Application2** down then all the messages are received by **Application1**. So far, everything working properly.

**THE PROBLEM:** the problem I have appears when I am voluntary blocking for example **Application1**. Let's say I send the **FactAddedEvent**, it's received by **Application1** but in the consuming method of the handler I set a breakpoint and I wait there. Therefore here I am voluntary blocking **Application1**. Now what I would expect is that since **Application1** is blocked, RabbitMQ will deliver all the next events I throw to ONLY **Application2**. Instead what it just does is: once RabbitMQ sends it to **Application1** once it sends it to **Application2**, no matter what. So in **Application1** there will be a queue of messages piling up even though **Application2** is free to do work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ channels have a PrefetchCount, which is the number of unacknowledged messages the broker will send to a consumer before pausing to wait for those messages to be acknowledged. By default, MassTransit sets this to 16, or the number of CPU cores x 2, whichever is greater. This setting is for each receive endpoint.

When running multiple instances, the broker will decide based on its algorithm which channel/consumer receives the message. The rule is to deliver messages directly to consumers with available prefetch to avoid an initial write to disk. Once all consumers prefetch limits are reached, messages are buffered.

Even in a breakpoint, the server thinks you're still alive and kicking, so it will continue to send messages until you fill up.

With the configuration you're using, you can [create a `ConsumerDefinition`](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/#definition) for your consumer to change that prefetch value for the receive endpoint. You can also just configure the consumer inline, using the [`.Endpoint()`](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/#consumer-registration) syntax:

```
x.AddConsumer<FactAddedFirstHandler>()
    .Endpoint(x => x.PrefetchCount = 1);
```

*That count is really low, and I wouldn't recommend that value in production, but for your testing it is fine.*

Hopefully that gives you some tools to get things working the way you expect.

Comment: It works great! Thanks a lot for the very clear explanation. I will be working with this tech stack in the coming days, so maybe expect some other question anytime soon :)